# Return result as anonymous object issue

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have ran into the following issue: when I execute query that return result in anonymous object :

```
var query = this.GraphClient.Cypher
.Match($"(e:{SystemNodeLabelEnum.Product.ToString()} {{MyId: "{myId}"}})")
.Return(e => new { SystemNode = e.As<SystemNode>() })
.OrderBy("e.NodeId")
.Skip(offset)
.Limit(limit);
```

this query throw exception:

```
Exception:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Inner exception:
Conversion of ZonedDateTime to INode is not supported.
   at Neo4j.Driver.V1.TemporalValue.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Convert.cs:line 377
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Convert.cs:line 315
   at Neo4j.Driver.V1.ValueExtensions.As[T](Object value)
   at Neo4jClient.StatementResultHelper.Parse[T](IRecord record, String identifier, IGraphClient graphClient)
```

When i have changed the return type to be the concrete object (not anonymous ) as following:

```
public class SystemNodeContainer
{
   public SystemNode Node { get; set; }
}
```

the same query execute properly and return the correct result.

```
var query = this.GraphClient.Cypher
.Match($"(e:{SystemNodeLabelEnum.Product.ToString()} {{MyId: "{myId}"}})")
.Return(e => new SystemNodeContainer { SystemNode = e.As<SystemNode>() })
.OrderBy("e.NodeId")
.Skip(offset)
.Limit(limit);
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: The exception, if i assume correctly, must be something like `Cannot cast object to SystemNode` or similar. In this case, you must cast the type `object` to your desired type, with something like `(SystemNode)myObject.....`.

Comment: Aousaf rashid I attempted that but the result was the same.

Comment: I guess this Return() method requires either a generic type parameter or have known datatype. In 2nd case, it has a known type. But in the 1st case you have send an anonymous object and also not specified type in the generic parameter.
Ref: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#returns

Comment: One of the properties in my custom class SystemNode is of type DateTime and in the neo4j database the relevant property is of type datetime and lookes like that : "2020-02-13T09:29:20.4700000"
I have debugged the BoltGraphClient source code and found that when ParseAnonymousAsDynamic method from StatementResultHelper class in client attempt to parse the datetime property from database throw the exception described in the post above.
When i have changed the type of datetime property in the neo4j graph ti string the problem was solved and anonymouse parser work properly.